# Thumbnail isn't refresh immediately

Tags: android, thumbnails, mediastore

I'm making a file manager in which picture items have a small thumbnail.

I get thumbnail image by using `MediaStore`. Everything works fine. But when I rename or move a file, the thumbnail does not show up.

I've found a piece of code to refresh `MediaStore`:

```
getActivity().sendBroadcast(
  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
             Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

It worked but I must wait 4 or 5 second and refresh, then the thumbnail updates.

How to get thumbnail of image immediately after rename or moving?

Comment: give it in a thread.........

Answer (score 2):

What happen if you use [ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) instead of `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED`, (i.e. trigger a refresh for a single file instead of for the complete directory hierarchy) ?

You will need to replace the URI of the directory with the URI of the file, obtained for example using [Uri.fromFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29).

When you move or rename a file you should refresh the old and the new URIs.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to update one specific image in Android is using ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE intent. And for smoother

You can check it at [Basic Photo Handling Training](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery) in Android Developer Site.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

If you want to show new thumbnail immediately for some missing files, you can do it by yourself. First, check the MediaStore as before, and if the returned thumbnail is null then generate your own one using [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) or [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).

And, For handling a bitmap and displaying it, there is a quiet [straightforward sample](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) in Android Training Course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the scan directly on the directory you are changing? So instead of

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

something like

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/your/folder")));
```

An alternative would be to manually use [ThumbnailUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually sending Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast intent is really ugly. Read this post http://androidyue.github.io/blog/2014/01/19/scan-media-files-in-android   As to renaming files.   You should remove the older file from the library and then add the new one into the library. I think this could help you.